# Display different splash screens depending on conditions

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

What I want to do is display a splash screen of a daytime picture if it is between certain times, then a night time picture if it is not in between those times. First, I am wondering if this is even possible. I am using Xamarin Forms for this project, but even having the code for iOS or Android would help. For Android, the code that I have right now just displays a splash screen. Im just unsure if there is anyway to have this change.

Styles.axml

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

MainActivity.cs

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", //Indicates the theme to use for this activity
         MainLauncher = true, //Set it as boot activity
         NoHistory = true)] //Doesn't place it in back stack
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); //Let's wait awhile...
        this.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not possible at least in iOS. You can make a "fake splash" view controller that would appear right after splash screen hides but not sure if that's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I would strongly urge you to follow [this tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) for creating splash screens the correct way. I do not know how well this would translate to Xamarin (as I have not worked with the platform), but the same concepts should apply.

---

From the answer you posted, it looks like you are just trying to change the splash screen based on whether it is day or night. This can be done easily with `night` or `notnight` [resource qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html?utm_campaign=android_launch_supportlibrary23.2_022216&utm_source=anddev&utm_medium=blog#NightQualifier).

For example, if you use a drawable for your splash screen, you can create a `drawable-night` folder. Then, place the drawable for your day splash screen in the `drawable` folder, and a drawable for your night splash screen in the `drawable-night` folder (make sure both drawables have the same name).

Comment: Is there any way to change `android:windowBackground` according to app specific locale or according to some value in `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: @NikhilManapure You could specify different background based on locale using "Language and Region" [resource qualifiers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#AlternativeResources). As for `SharedPreferences`, that would require a much more in-depth answer; in short you *should* be able to change the background by supplying a separate theme (using `setTheme()`) before you call `super.onCreate()`, but I am not sure how that would effect the load time of the application.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested or has this issue in the future, this is what I ended up doing in Android (haven't looked at iOS yet). I think it is as close to having 2 different splash screens based on times as I can get. It initially loads a black screen, then based on the time of day, it loads either the daytime or nighttime picture:

In styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">  
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>  <!--Daytime--> 
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Splash2" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash2</item>  <!--Nighttime-->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.Splash3" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash3</item>  <!--All black-->
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

In MainActivity.cs

```
 [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash3", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity3 : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);

        if ((System.DateTime.Now.Hour >= 6) && (System.DateTime.Now.Hour <= 18))
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(SplashActivity1));
        }

        else
        {
            StartActivity(typeof(SplashActivity2));

        }
    }


    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity1 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 3000; // 3 sec.
            timer.AutoReset = false; // Do not reset the timer after it's elapsed
            timer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            };
            timer.Start();


        }
    }

    [Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash2", NoHistory = true)]
    public class SplashActivity2 : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 3000; // 3 sec.
            timer.AutoReset = false; // Do not reset the timer after it's elapsed
            timer.Elapsed += (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
            };
            timer.Start();

        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not be using a `Timer` in your [splash screens](http://cyrilmottier.com/2012/05/03/splash-screens-are-evil-dont-use-them/)! Actually, you should not be using [timers at all](http://www.mopri.de/2010/timertask-bad-do-it-the-android-way-use-a-handler/)... You shouldn't even be using a splash screen if your app [doesn't need it](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/help.html).

Comment: Thanks for the input. I tried using System.Threading.Thread.Sleep but I couldn't get that working. This is my first time working with mobile development, so a lot of what I have done is just from online tutorials. I don't disagree with not using splash screens if not needed and have read it a lot while searching for this answer, but its a requirement of this project so I have to do it

Comment: Initially had not realized that you were using Xamarin, that's my fault. The Xamarin `Timer` class is different from the Java `Timer` class. But I think you missed my point about why you shouldn't use splash screens. Even if the project requires a splash screen, I would hope that it is not required it to display it for 3 seconds. A splash screen should only be displayed for as long as it takes the application to load.